# Native crashes on UE4 android game only in distribution build

Tags: android, unreal, google-play

As I build my game for development mode and install it directly from apk file to my device, it runs without errors and doesn't crash, there are in-game ads and it is able to get variables from game-saves.

But once I build with `Shipping` and `Distribution` tags and upload it to Google Play I get errors on all devices that it is tested. (Installing directly through apk also crashes it.)

Here are backtraces-

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'motorola/harpia/harpia:6.0.1/MPI24.241-2.35-1/1:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'p1b0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 14791, tid: 14855, name: Thread-932  >>> com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000001  r3 00000000
    r4 000084fa  r5 95bd3280  r6 00000000  r7 00002888
    r8 9dbb5fd4  r9 980edb20  sl 96d7f100  fp 9dbb5f88
    ip a274d504  sp 9dbb5f60  lr 9fd0eed4  pc a162ad24  cpsr 20070010
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0344dd24  /data/app/com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet-1/lib/arm/libUE4.so (_ZN22FSessionServicesModule13StartupModuleEv+72)
    #01 pc 01b32058  /data/app/com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet-1/lib/arm/libUE4.so (_ZN14FModuleManager27LoadModuleWithFailureReasonE5FNameR17EModuleLoadResultb+432)
    #02 pc 01b31e98  /data/app/com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet-1/lib/arm/libUE4.so (_ZN14FModuleManager10LoadModuleE5FNameb+76)
    #03 pc 0196bee8  /data/app/com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet-1/lib/arm/libUE4.so (_ZN11FEngineLoop4InitEv+1752)
    #04 pc 0196aa10  /data/app/com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet-1/lib/arm/libUE4.so (_Z11AndroidMainP11android_app+2568)
    #05 pc 0196e618  /data/app/com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet-1/lib/arm/libUE4.so (android_main+108)
    #06 pc 01981bc8  /data/app/com.MadElectron.FarmPlanet-1/lib/arm/libUE4.so
    #07 pc 00041acb  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
    #08 pc 00019355  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Transfering to 4.19.2 solves the problem